# Floating .field-item image to left of content type rather than centering it In Drupal

Tags: html, css, drupal

I'm relatively new to Drupal and so-so with CSS and am trying to float the image on a particular content type to the left of the content rather than having it center on the page on a row by itself.  The purpose of the page is to have a list of items (like a catalog) and have an image to the left with the various descriptive fields to the right.

Using what I've found online I was able to get this on my CSS which almost works but after the first line being properly located to the right of the image the next line appears below the image.  I would like all of them to be to the right, next to the image.

Because Drupal is generating the code I don't have the ability to easily change the HTML (though with work this is theoretically possible) but changes in the CSS are simple

```
.field-item img {

  /* Shift "thumbail" images to the left */

  /* new code to shift image to the left */
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;

  /* -- old code to center image
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  */
}
```

My theme is derived from danland. The page itself can be seen at http://blog.creatingorigami.com/content/eric%E2%80%99s-lotus

Any leads would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why change html code? This is crap. You can full styling html for use css styles.

I dont know if I understand right. This problem is clearfix hack, your page contains clearfixs.

Fastest solution.Change css property clear from both on value inherit.In system css called system.base.css. Path something as ..(root)/modules/system/.etc

After will be all contains on right side.

```css
.clearfix:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: inherit; /*changed property!*/
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comfortable, but not clean solution is violent rewrite property 
 to the root css style.

```css
.clearfix:after {
    clear: inherit !important;
    }
```

Comment: Awesome lead... that got me in the right direction!  Here's the correct fix which I was able to divine from your suggestion:

`div.field.clearfix:after  {
 display: inline-block;
}`

Comment: Certainly, this is good. Always is better use direct more detailed selector.  Thats one thing. Next I exactly did not understand some details, for better fixation. But I like, that it working!